# Multidrop bus protocol on the BeagleBone Black PRU

Tags: uart, serial, rs232, beaglebone-black

I am truying to implement the MDB protocol on the BeagleBone Black, the problem is :
the protocol requires a 9 bit data via UART (9th bit used to differentiate if the sent/received data frame is an adress or data) and the BeagleBopne Black UARTs doesn't support 9 bit characters, I decided to use the PRU_HW_UART but the last doesn't support 9 bit mode also, is there a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Doesn't the PRU allow to program whatever you want? But still this is just the tip of an iceberg, you would have also to patch the OS to accept 9 bit UART.

Comment: I found from TI e2e forums that there's a Soft UART implementation on the am335x (BeagleBone Black Processor), I am trying to understand the requirments and try to develop a  9 bit UART

Comment: How would you use it? The higher level function that would call your driver doesn't support 9bit, at least Linux doesn't.. It depends if your vending machine will be implemented entirely in C code or you will have an OS, for example Linux.

Comment: The BeagleBone Black processor has two built in RISC cores ( programmable real time units ) according to TI [1], these units can be firmware programmed to use the UART to perform 9 bit characters per transfer and now I am struggling with compilation errors
[1] : http://software-dl.ti.com/processor-sdk-rtos/esd/docs/latest/rtos/PRU_ICSS.html#pru-icss-uart